# Dynamically show images in Tableau

Tags: image, visualization, tableau-api

Is there a way to dynamically show images in a dashboard. The name of the image file would be linked to a dimension, and the image files are all stored under one directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Put all your images on a web server in a directory together.
2. Rename the images so they match the members of your dimension.
3. In the Tableau dashboard, insert an HTML widget.
4. Create a sheet that has the dimension on it.
5. Put the sheet in the dashboard.
6. Create a URL action from the sheet to the HTML widget.
7. Edit the URL so it will have the path to your image directory followed by the dimension.
8. Make the action trigger on select.

Comment: Hi Austin, Can you please share any sample workbook for the above scenario if you have any.